# React Native can you puts views, with other elements inside, inside a ScrollView

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create an application using *React-Native* the page i am working on takes data it is given from a web server to populate a list. i am trying to display 20 entries, this includes an image and a name. i would like to create 20 views that contain this information in a scroll-able view. When i put a view inside of the scroll view it disappears. I am having trouble figuring out how scroll views work exactly, could someone please explain how this is done?

Code:

```
<View style={commonStyle.container}>

{/* Scrollable View */}
<ScrollView style={toysListStyle.MainContent}>

  <View style={toysListStyle.ToyEntry}>
    <Image resizeMode="contain" style={toysListStyle.ToyPicture}
        source={{uri: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png'}}></Image>
    <View style={toysListStyle.ToyNameView}>
      <Text>Name</Text>
    </View>
  </View>

</ScrollView>

</View>


const toysListStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    MainContent: {
        position: "absolute",
        left: "0%",
        top: "33.5%",
        width: "100%",
        height: "60.5%",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)",
        flex: 1
    },
    ToyEntry: {
        position: "absolute",
        width: "100%",
        height: "25%",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        flex: 1
   },
   ToyPicture: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: "5%",
        left: "5%",
        height: "90%",
        width: "60%"
   },
   ToyNameView: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: "
        right: "
        height: "100%",
        width: "
        justifyContent: '
        alignItems: 'center'
   }
});

const commonStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        height: windowHeight,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "white", 
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
},
```

I left out the information of the entire page because there is a lot but this is where i am having the problem. If i Change the ScrollView to a View then the View inside shows up, but in a ScrollView It doesn't appear. What am i missing?

Comment: Unless you share your code, it's not possible to tell why your `View` disappears inside `ScrollView`. We can put any component inside `ScrollView`. BTW, you can use `FlatList` or `SectionList` to show scroll-able views.

Comment: put the code in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You did all things right but...

```
  ToyEntry: {
        position: "absolute",
        width: "100%",
        height: "25%",// This will work if parent contain fixed height like device height or in points and it will divide those value in that ratio...
        backgroundColor: "red",
        flex: 1
   }
```

> So you can add fixed height to ToyEntry or you can add fixed height to
>   its parent...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to view the content inside `ScrollView` with a bit change in `ToyEntry` style, just add `height` to absolute value instead of `%`

```
ToyEntry: {
  position: "absolute",
  width: "100%",
  height: 250,
  backgroundColor: "red",
  flex: 1
}
```

Also, the image that you have shared, for some reason is not showing so I changed the image link also to see the result

```
<Image resizeMode="contain" style={styles.ToyPicture}
       source={{uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1'}}
/>
```